# PayPal SandBox error using buy now button

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a page on my computer that has a simple buy now button with the following code:

```
<script src="paypal-button-minicart.min.js"></script>
<script src="paypal-button.min.js?merchant=8TYNWA5KGBSPE"
    data-button="buynow"
    data-name="My product"
    data-amount="15.00"
></script>
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgibin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="8TYNWA5KGBSPE">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Football lessons">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="15.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal � The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

But I get the error:

> PayPal cannot process this transaction because of a problem with the seller's website

When I click on it, I'm logged in as a test user on the sandbox and I don't know what else to try.  Why am I getting the 'cannot process this transaction' error?

Comment: Can you try creating a non hosted clear text button so that we can see what is being passed over, and what may be causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate a non-hosted/clear text button follow these steps:

1. Log in your PayPal account www.paypal.com
2. Click the tab "Merchant Services" to access the Merchant Tools tab.
3. In the Website Payment Standard section select the type of button you would like to create (Buy Now, Add to Cart, Donation, Etc…).
4. Click "Create your button now" to access to the PayPal Button Factory.
5. Fill out the fields you will need in your button (Item name, Price, Currency…).
6. Click the tab "Step 2: Track inventory (optional)" then uncheck the box "Save button at PayPal".
7. Click on "Create Button".
8. The encrypted HTML code of your button will be displayed.
9. Click on the link "Remove code protection"
10. The HTML code of your button will be displayed, click "Select Code" and copy it to your website.

You can also find a helpful video [here](https://www.paypaltech.com/videotutorial/en/no_h_no_enc_buynow/buynow_nohost_noencrypt.htm).

Comment: You are setting "8TYNWA5KGBSPE" as the value for the business id.  I am not showing this being a valid account in the sandbox.  Where did you get this id at?  Is this from your live account?  If this is from your live account or live button, you would need to either live the URL pointing to the live site, or set up a sandbox account and use the email address or merchant id from that account.